# Heroku The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I´m trying to deploy a sample ruby on rails app on Heroku following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a20zOThEFTQ

I had some problems with the ssh keys that I already fixed, so, everything looks good, however when I run `heroku open` the browser opens with an error page with message: The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

Please see the heroku logs:

```
C:\dev\app>heroku open
Opening salty-badlands-1469... done

C:\dev\app>heroku logs
2014-04-26T13:03:44.794940+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795052+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-04-26T13:02:54.409527 #2]
FATAL -- :
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795070+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795076+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795068+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795072+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795066+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795074+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795078+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795081+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795095+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795083+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/
rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795087+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795089+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795091+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795093+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795096+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795098+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795100+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795101+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-04-26T13:03:44.793234 #2]
 INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 88.11.116.37 at 2014-04-26 13:03:44 +0000
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795104+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-04-26T13:03:44.794799 #2]
FATAL -- :
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795124+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795126+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795130+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795132+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795128+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795134+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795135+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795137+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795146+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795140+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795148+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795150+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795142+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ra
ck-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795152+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795175+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795159+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795177+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-26T13:03:44.795160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-26T13:11:10.035239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=
salty-badlands-1469.herokuapp.com request_id=60af40e8-b3e8-4c83-ade6-5087d6fb5d4
7 fwd="88.11.116.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-04-26T13:18:03+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-04-26T13:18:27+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-04-26T13:18:27.700872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to startin
g
2014-04-26T13:18:27.550607+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fc655f2 by roberto.chingon@
hotmail.com
2014-04-26T13:18:27.550693+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by roberto.chin
gon@hotmail.com
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257418+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-26 13:18:31] FATAL SignalE
xception: SIGTERM
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257424+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257426+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257427+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257438+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257439+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257441+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257443+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257444+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257446+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257448+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257449+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257455+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-26 13:18:31] INFO  going t
o shutdown ...
2014-04-26T13:18:31.257518+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-26 13:18:31] INFO  WEBrick
::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282043+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-04-26T13:11:10.034983 #2]
 INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 88.11.116.37 at 2014-04-26 13:11:10 +0000
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282049+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-04-26T13:11:10.035960 #2]
FATAL -- :
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282051+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282053+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282072+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282067+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282069+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282074+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282056+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282066+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282060+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282076+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282061+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282063+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282064+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282080+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282078+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282084+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282087+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282089+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282091+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282093+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-04-26T13:18:31.282095+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-04-26T13:18:30.612186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2014-04-26T13:18:32.675820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-04-26T13:18:33.941417+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-26 13:18:33] INFO  ruby 2.
0.0 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
2014-04-26T13:18:33.941390+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-26 13:18:33] INFO  WEBrick
 1.3.1
2014-04-26T13:18:33.941916+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-26 13:18:33] INFO  WEBrick
::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=15317
2014-04-26T13:18:31.388439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 15317 -e production`
2014-04-26T13:18:34.350752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2014-04-26T13:18:55.342887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=
salty-badlands-1469.herokuapp.com request_id=594aee6a-53ec-4c48-8b6e-c04a6bb308f
1 fwd="88.11.116.37" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=255ms status=404 bytes=1616
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have is here:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")
```

I would suggest looking at your `config/routes.rb` file & seeing where your `root to: "controller#action"` command is. If you don't have it, you should put one in, else you need to amend it to point to the right controller/action